# Moving Newly Added Columns using Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I have a script that adds in new data daily from our production line. However since it just appends the data the format is not the way we need it to be for presentation.

The format we need is :
Order # - Date - Line - Priority

The format we import is :
Date - Line - Priority - Order #

This is the script that we use to add data in daily:

```
  function CopySchedule() {

  var Production = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ProductionID"); //Production Schedule
  var ScheduleSheet = Production.getSheets()[0]; //Production Schedule Sheet 1
  var startRow = 2;
  var startCol = 1;
  var numRows = 1000;
  var numCol = 25;
  var ScheduleData = ScheduleSheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCol); //Get info from Production Schedule
  var Schedule = ScheduleData.getValues(); // Get Values
  var MySchedule = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Current Spreadsheet
  var MySheet = MySchedule.getSheets()[5]; //Current Sheet on Spreadsheet
  var now = new Date(); //Today's date
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(now, "EST", "M-dd-yy"); //Reformat today date
    
  for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x++) 
  {

     if (Schedule[x][0] == today) //if date is today
       {
          MySheet.appendRow(Schedule[x]); //add row from schedule to bottom of current sheet
        }
  }
  

}
```

[This is how we want the Data to be presented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A596W.jpg)

[This is how it is added into the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86szZ.jpg)

Macros wouldn't be sufficient since the amount of orders we do daily isn't a fixed # unless there's a way to have a macro only select the new daily data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem statement:

You need to store the values in the desired order. Based on the screenshots provided, the right order should be:

```
[Schedule[x][3],Schedule[x][0],Schedule[x][1],Schedule[x][2]]
```

### Solutions:

There are two ways you can acomplish that. One way is to use `appendRow()` which is not recommended especially when the dataset becomes large and the second way is to use `setValues()` which is way more efficient.

### 1st Solution with [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents):

```
function CopySchedule() {

  var Production = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ProductionID"); //Production Schedule
  var ScheduleSheet = Production.getSheets()[0]; //Production Schedule Sheet 1
  var startRow = 2;
  var startCol = 1;
  var numRows = 1000;
  var numCol = 25;
  var ScheduleData = ScheduleSheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCol); //Get info from Production Schedule
  var Schedule = ScheduleData.getValues(); // Get Values
  var MySchedule = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Current Spreadsheet
  var MySheet = MySchedule.getSheets()[5]; //Current Sheet on Spreadsheet
  var now = new Date(); //Today's date
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(now, "EST", "M-dd-yy"); //Reformat today date
    
  for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x++) 
  {

     if (Schedule[x][0] == today) //if date is today
       {
          MySheet.appendRow([Schedule[x][3],Schedule[x][0],Schedule[x][1],Schedule[x][2]]); 
        }
  }
  

}
```

### 2nd Solution with [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) - Recommended:

```
 function CopySchedule() {

  var Production = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ProductionID"); //Production Schedule
  var ScheduleSheet = Production.getSheets()[0]; //Production Schedule Sheet 1
  var startRow = 2;
  var startCol = 1;
  var numRows = 1000;
  var numCol = 25;
  var ScheduleData = ScheduleSheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCol); //Get info from Production Schedule
  var Schedule = ScheduleData.getValues(); // Get Values
  var MySchedule = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Current Spreadsheet
  var MySheet = MySchedule.getSheets()[5]; //Current Sheet on Spreadsheet
  var now = new Date(); //Today's date
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(now, "EST", "M-dd-yy"); //Reformat today date
    
  data = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x++) 
  {

     if (Schedule[x][0] == today) //if date is today
       {
          data.push([Schedule[x][3],Schedule[x][0],Schedule[x][1],Schedule[x][2]]);
        }
  }
  
MySheet.getRange(MySheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what we needed, thank you very much! If I had more data than the initial 4 columns, would I have to continue the `Schedule[x][n]` chain? or is there a shorthand for inputting all the way up to row z?

Comment: @Index since the Schedule data is not ordered properly, you have to specify it manually.